# Rails 5.2.3 Sending AJAX request with JSON but not receiving key-value pairs which have + sign as value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, promise

I'm using Rails 5.2.3 and trying to send an AJAX request that includes a JSON representation of a callflow(Don't worry about what it is) object. This JSON representation is in a textarea with id "newCallflowJsonDisplay". As an example:

```
{
  "callflow": [
    {
      "action": "dial",
      "options": {
        "destination": 12121218
      },
      "label": "-"
    }
  ]
}
```

The javascript code I'm using is:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        Rails.ajax({
            url: `some url`,
            data: `callflow_json=${document.getElementById('newCallflowJsonDisplay').value}`,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response){resolve(response)},
            error: function(response){reject(response)}
        });
    }).then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(function(error){
        logError(error);
    })
```

With the JSON representation and code above, everything worked just as I expected. Notice that the value for key "label" is "-". 
In my log I can see

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"callflow_json"=>"{\n  \"callflow\": [\n    {\n      \"action\": \"dial\",\n      \"options\": {\n        \"destination\": 12121218\n      },\n      \"label\": \"-\"\n    }\n  ]\n}", "controller"=>"callflows", "action"=>"manipulate", "callflow_id"=>"61"} permitted: false>
```

However, if I use the following JSON where the value for key "label" is "+":

```
{
  "callflow": [
    {
      "action": "dial",
      "options": {
        "destination": 12121218
      },
      "label": "+"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can see in the log:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"callflow_json"=>"{\n  \"callflow\": [\n    {\n      \"action\": \"dial\",\n      \"options\": {\n        \"destination\": 12121218\n      },\n      \"label\": \" \"\n    }\n  ]\n}", "controller"=>"callflows", "action"=>"manipulate", "callflow_id"=>"63"} permitted: false>
```

As you can see, even though I've made sure the textarea has the correct JSON and the "+" sign is present, when it reaches the server, the "+" sign is not present and my log does not show it at all.

I've tried using letters, "*", and "/" as well. All of them work, except for "+".

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't '+' represent a < space >  in query strings? Maybe you need to urlencode before sending...

Answer (score 0):

So I believe that when ajax is automatically parsing/stringifying your data, it is losing the plus sign. One way to get around this is to basically parse it yourself by doing something along these lines:
`var json = '{ "callflow_json": { "callflow": [{ "action": "dial", "options": { "destination": 12121218 }, "label": "+" }] }}';`
 And then in your ajax request just pass in json as your data. This way the ajax request will correctly parse it for you.

Additionally, I am noticing that in your parameters it says that it is not permitted, I think that this will give you some problems later on.

I believe a fix for this prospective problem would be something along the lines of `params.require(:your_model).permit(:callflow_json)`

I hope that this helped and that it answered your question!

Comment: Thanks Luke, here is the log when the value for "label" is "+": `App 9252 output:   Parameters: {"callflow_json"=>"{\n  \"callflow\": [\n    {\n      \"action\": \"dial\",\n      \"options\": {\n        \"destination\": 12121218\n      },\n      \"label\": \" \"\n    }\n  ]\n}", "callflow_id"=>"68"}`

And when the value is "-": `App 9252 output:   Parameters: {"callflow_json"=>"{\n  \"callflow\": [\n    {\n      \"action\": \"dial\",\n      \"options\": {\n        \"destination\": 12121218\n      },\n      \"label\": \"-\"\n    }\n  ]\n}", "callflow_id"=>"23"}`

I've permitted callfow_json